# Space with hamming distance at least 2.

Tags: coding-theory

Let $X=\{0,...,2^n-1\}$. Is there a $Y\subseteq X$ with $|Y|=2^{n-1}$ and such that $d(x,y)\geq 2$ for any $x,y\in Y$, where $d$ is the hamming distance (number of on bits of the xor operation)?

I know [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891528/generating-a-binary-code-with-maximized-hamming-distance) is more general, but I am only interested in the specific case of $d_\min=2$, for which according to the [link](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/binary-1.html) provided in one of the answers, such a $Y$ exists.

Comment: $Y\subseteq X$ and $|Y|=2^n$ would imply $Y=X$.

Comment: My fault. The statement is now correct. It is $|Y|=2^{n-1}$

Comment: Then your question is very close to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062577).

Comment: @metamorphy It is indeed a duplicate and I have voted to close this one.